# MVC3 Dropdown List in grid column, get selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a column in a grid that contains dropdown list.
The row also has a link which takes me to an action method.
I need the selected value of the dropdown list in that row and pass it to the method.

I have used jquery in the past to get the selected value of a dropdown list...but not when there are multiple drop down lists.
Can you give me some ideas on how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to write

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('select.SomeClass').val()
```

This code will get the `<tr>` containing `this`, then find a `select` in the row.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I will try this.